# Has anyone ever had success being granted Google+ Pages API access?

Tags: google-plus

I'm working on a social media / reputation management aggregation project and I'd love to be able to integrate Google Pages access for businesses to be able to see their online presence in Google.

There's a form to fill out for Pages API access, but I've never heard back from anyone and there's no means to be able to follow up.  My question is: has anyone ever been granted access to the Google Pages API?  Is there something special I can do to be granted access, or does anyone know how to be grated access into this secret garden?

Comment: Same pain here. I am working on an editorial calendar and Google+ pages integration is really important for my users. I applied few months ago but never heard back from Google

Answer (score 1):

There are [many companies](http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html) that have been granted access to this API.

As you might imagine, many people probably fill out that form and the vast majority will not hear back. There are no published guidelines that detail what types of applicants will be considered, but based on the linked listing they likely need to demonstrate impact and a reputable system that is already in place.

My only suggestion is to really fill out that form with a very strong business case and be sure to provide as much detail as possible to help your case.

Comment: Doesn't that pose a "chicken and egg" scenario though?  I need Google Pages API access to demonstrate a reputable system... but without the API access I can't build the system.  Seems... counter-intuitive.